# How to style action in MS teams adaptive card

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

My intention is to emphasize button in the adaptive card, I noticed that [adaptive card designer](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/) allows to choose from 3 different styles eg Default, Positive, Destructive, when you chose anything else than Default one it doesn't get applied neither in card designer nor in real MS teams message, here's the example of the message sent

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.2",
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Action.Submit",
            "style": "destructive"
        }
    ]
}
```

what I see as result

[image]

Does anyone know how to change default action design in MS teams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Bug in Adaptive Card action button styling. I've filed a Bug for Adaptive Card team. I will update you once this got resolved

Comment: got you, very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Teams Does not support Card action button styling in adaptive card. This is by design.

Comment: What's the reason to leave it in adaptivecards.io and documentation then?